# Array of objects to grid/table in Angular

Tags: json, angular, html-table, grid

I have data as an array of objects like this:

```
[{
    "x":1,
    "y":10,
    "val": 13
},
{
    "x":1,
    "y":20,
    "val": 15
},
{
    "x":2,
    "y":10,
    "val": 12
},
{
    "x":2,
    "y":20,
    "val": 16
}
]
```

I want this data to be displayed in an HTML table like this:

```
        1    2

10   |  13   12
20   |  15   16
```

How to proceed?

Comment: I think you want to look into `display:grid` and the `grid-area` property

Comment: I think my problem isn't related to styling with CSS. I need a way to show this data in HTML code with some tags containing ngFor I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I would parse the data so you have a 2d array. Something like this:

```
[
  [13,12],
  [15,16],
]
```

and then use two nested ng-for loops to render the content:

```
<div *ngFor="let row of matrix">
    <span *ngFor="let item of row">{{item}}</span>
</div>
```

and place the headers appart.